# For continuous $h:\mathbb{R\longrightarrow R}$, prove $h(x)=0$ for x in $\mathbb{Q}$ implies $h(x)=0$ for x in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

The problem statement is as follows: For continuous $h:\mathbb{R\longrightarrow R}$, prove $h(x)=0$ for $x$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ implies $h(x)=0$ for $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

My attempt feels a bit awkward and I was hoping to find a more proper proof, in the likely event that mine is flawed:

Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that $\exists a \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(a)=b \neq 0$. Since $h$ is continuous, it is continuous at $a$. Applying the definition of continuity, For all $\epsilon >0, \exists \delta$ such that $|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |h(x)-h(a)|<\epsilon \Rightarrow |0-b|<\epsilon$ (we can assume $h(x)$ is $0$ because if not, the proof is concluded) $\Rightarrow -\epsilon<b<\epsilon$. Since $b$ is fixed but $\epsilon$ can always be closer to $0$, we can choose $\epsilon$ such that $-\epsilon<b<\epsilon$ is false. Therefore, such $a$ does not exist. $\square$

I especially dislike how hand-wavy the end of the proof is; there must be a better way. How can this be improved? Is it even valid?

Comment: Use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Since there is no mention of the rationals in your proof, Christopher, it can't be a proof of what you are trying to prove.

Comment: Yes your proof works, though it needs more details

Comment: The proof isn't just lacking in details, it is flawed.  It assumes it can reduce to the assumption that $h(x)=0$ because "if not, the proof is concluded", which is not the case at all.  As Gerry mentioned, it must invoke density of rationals, as it can only use $h(x)=0$ when $x$ is rational.

Comment: Indeed, the epsilon estimation only holds for certain $x$, but $a$ is one such $x$ with $h(x)\not=0$

Answer (score 2):

$h(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ implies that $\forall x_n \to x$, $\lim_{n \to \infty}h(x_n) = h(x)$. On the other hand, $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists \{x_n\} \subset \mathbb{Q}$ such that $x_n \to x$.